# Error declaring variables in typescript with VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Typescript and I'm using VSCode, I have two files and I declared a variable in each file with the same name, "a" as tuple type.
[image]

and as an array

[image]

When I close a tab this error goes away in the tap that remains open, so does it have sense?, I assume that this files are separated therefore its errors.

Thanks. Josh

Comment: Since it is not clear from screenshots, I will assume that you declare everything in global scope = on "first level". Since you have no tsconfig file, you can imagine that compiler takes all files and concatenates them into one big file. In that file that `let a` statement is doubled and that leads to error.

Comment: thanks for answering, yes sr, I don't have declared the tsconfig, I didn't know about the file concatenation, thank you, all clear.